# get_the_term_list & url

Tags: thumbnails, terms

I have 2 custom post type and i want to link them together with an **url** from the first one and a **image** from the second one.

I can get the **title** and the **url** of my taxonomy  like that :

( CPT  = 'traductions', TAX = 'nom-origin' )

```
$url = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'nom-origin');
```

But i don't want a title, i just want to link this **url** with this **thumbnail**
that i can get like that : 
(CPT  = 'livre')

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'livre',
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'ASC' 
    );
    $livres = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $livres->have_posts() ) {
        while( $livres->have_posts() ) {
            $livres->the_post();
?>
<?php           
global $post;

<a href="<?php echo $something ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('thumbnail_size_w'), array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
```

So, what should i write instead of *$something*  ?

Or i am completely wrong about the whole approach ? I have been stuck on this for a while so any help would be appreciate.

thanks

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are trying to do here. `get_the_term_list` returns all the terms associated with the given post ID, as a string of anchor tags. So, it provides (potentially multiple) links, not URLs. Also, why are you declaring global $post immediately after the start of your loop? And how is the nom-origin CPT related to livre?

Comment: You are right,  get_the_term_list returns a list of links with the name of my taxonomy(nom-origin). What i would like is to use these links and use them with the thumbnails of an other CPT. I can display these thumbnails with the loop above. I just don't know how to put the link and the thumbnail together. And i am using global $post after the start of my loop because i have been told to do so. Thanks for helping.